# How to write a number animation on the mouse button press event in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle 
{
  width: 100; height: 100
  color: "red"

   MouseArea 
   {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed:
    {
      NumberAnimation 
      { 
        target: parent.x
        to: 50; 
        duration: 1000 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect this code to shift the `x` position of the rectangle on the button press event, but this does nothing.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining an NumberAnimation in a signal handler, it's not going to work properly. Furthermore, NumberAnimation target should be an item, and here you are targeting a property of an item. Here is your code corrected :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle 
{
  id: rect
  width: 100; height: 100
  color: "red"

   MouseArea 
   {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPressed:
    {
        animation.start()
    }

    NumberAnimation 
    { 
        id: animation
        target: rect
        property: "x"
        to: 50; 
        duration: 1000 
    }
  }
}
```

If your rectangle animation should revert when mouse is released, you would like to take benefit of a proper state definition, and animate property "x" at each state change (between default and "pressed" states. Here is a self contained example :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
  id: root
  width: 360
  height: 200

  Rectangle 
  {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    MouseArea 
    {
      id: mouse
      anchors.fill: parent
    }

    states: [
      State {
        name: "pressed"
        when: mouse.pressed

        PropertyChanges {
          target: rect
          x: 50
        }
      }
    ]

    Behavior on x {
      NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 } 
    }
  }
}
```

If you need more complex animation, define a proper `Transition`. A simple `Behavior`, here, is more readable I find.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle
{
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            animation.start();
        }
    }

    NumberAnimation on x {
        id: animation
        running: false

        to: 50
        duration: 1000
    }
}
```

From docs:

> NumberAnimation is a specialized PropertyAnimation that defines an animation to be applied when a numerical value changes.

So, you want not to animate on click, but you want to assign animation to x property of rectangle and start it on click.